# Merge multiple evensized vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++17, stdvector

I have n even sized `std::vector`s. Lets assume n=3 and size = 4:

```
std::vector<int> a {1,2,3,4};
std::vector<int> b {2,2,2,2};
std::vector<int> c {3,3,3,3};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> combinedVectors {a,b,c};
```

I want to retrieve an vector of size 4 which has its `i`th member being the sum of all the vectors' `i`th member.
In the example

```
std::vector<int> x{6,7,8,9};
```

What is the nicest generic way to build vector `x`? Please stick to cpp17 standard in your answer.

By nicest way I would like to stick to `<algorithm>` instead of using loops.

Comment: a loop that adds the elements and inserts them into an already properly sized vector? What is "nicest" ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Using algorithm header only instead of loops if possible.

Comment: I don't think there's any standard algorithm to operate on ranges of ranges. To use them, you'd have to roll out some class with iterators that allow to access different vectors stored in class. Quite possible, but probably not worth the effort over just writing two loops.

Comment: common misunderstanding:  "`<algorithm>` instead of using loops". Most algorithms are just a loop. I suppose you mean "handwritten loop", but often a handwritten loop is the "nicer" alternative when there is no algorithm that does what you want out of the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no algorithm that takes a range of ranges as parameter (well, they do, but sloppy speaking algorithms work on elements not on elements of elements). `std::ranges` would probaly help, but if you want to stick with C++17, you can only use an existing algorithm with some contortions or write your own.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename IT,typename...Args> 
void copy_sum(IT begin, IT end, IT to, Args... others) {
    for (; begin != end; ++begin,++to){
        *to = *begin + (*others++ + ...);
    }
}


int main(){
    std::vector<int> a {1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int> b {2,2,2,2};
    std::vector<int> c {3,3,3,3};
    //std::vector<std::vector<int>> combinedVectors {a,b,c};

    std::vector<int> result(a.size());
    copy_sum(a.begin(),a.end(),result.begin(),b.begin(),c.begin());

    for (auto e : result) std::cout << e << " ";    
}
```

Note that I didn't use `combinedVectors`. If you want to stay generic then pass iterators around not container. Though, the above could benefit from a helper that takes `begin` and `end` to a range of elements in `combinedVectors` and forwards their `begin` and `end` to `copy_sum`.

However, this is not really what I would call "nicest" and a simple loop is probably unbeatable in readability as long as you stay with C++17.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really determined to use `algorithm` library, you can have something like:

```cpp
std::vector<int> tmp;
std::vector<int> result;

std::transform(
    std::begin(a), std::end(a),
    std::begin(b),
    std::back_inserter(tmp),
    [](int a, int b) { return a + b; }
);

std::transform(
    std::begin(c), std::end(c),
    std::begin(tmp),
    std::back_inserter(result),
    [](int a, int b) { return a + b; }
);
```

The downside is that you would need one temporary `std::vector`.